# crear un .zip en java

Tags: java

Necesito crear un zip y dentro de esa compresión que escriba el `file`, necesito convertir los bytes a `file` para que escriba y lo guarde.

Acá dejo el método:

```
public static byte[] zipFiles(String resource, byte[] content ) throws Exception {

    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(resource ));
    ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(resource + ".zip");
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(resource);
    int len;
    len = in.read(resource.getBytes()); {
        zos.write(resource.getBytes(), 0, len);
    }
            in.close();
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.close();
            return resource.getBytes();
}
```

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista estas invirtiendo los pasos, primero debes de crear el archivo y luego zipearlo, no puedes zipear y luego querer crear el archivo en el zip. suerte

Comment: Es que  ese file tengo que transformarlo a bytes tambien

Comment: Para poder ayudar, puedes explicar como piensas utilizar `String resource, byte[] content` o que parámetros son los que envías, porque no veo que utilices  `content`, además si lo quieres guardar en un directorio o solo lo quieres en byte para realizar mas procesos.

Comment: Hola , el parametro resources es el nombre del archivo y el content es el contenido del file .No lo lo quiero guardar en un directorio si no en un Object Storage, en el cual lo tiene que guardar como bytes pero al descargarlo en .zip lo vea el contenido como un json.

Comment: Por eso abstrai el metodo del zip y luego se lo envio al Object Storage.Pero justamente mi problema es poder descargarlo y que vea el json porque ahora me al abrirlo me muestra el el archivo no es compatible,

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estas confundiendo las partes del código para crear el zip, por ejemplo en `ZipOutputStream` es la ruta y el nombre del zip a crear y en `new  ZipEntry(resource + ".zip");` es el nombre y la extensión del archivo que vas a agregar dentro del zip, te dejo un ejemplo con algunos comentarios para que te guíes:

```
public class ZipFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Dirección del archivo a agregar al zip
        String sourceFile = "C:\\clave.txt";
        // Dirección y nombre del zip a crear
        String dest = "C:\\ArchivoZip.zip";
        zipFiles(sourceFile, dest);
    }


    public static void zipFiles(String sourceFile, String dest) throws IOException {

        // ZIP de destino, url y nombre del zip
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        // Buscamos el archivo fisico
        File fileToZip = new File(sourceFile);
        //Convertimos el archivo a un InputStream y lo agregamos a una entrada del ZIP
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName());

        // Agregamos la entrada del zip con el archivo al archivo de salida.
        zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        
        // Cerramos los recursos.
        zipOut.close();
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias pero no lo quiero meter en un directorio.

Comment: por otro lado al abrie el .zip me dice que el formato no es compatible,por eso necesito convertirlo a json para que me muestre el contenido.

Comment: No entiendo tu proceso, lo mejor es que edites tu pregunta y describas correctamente lo que envías y lo que quieres hacer, porque no entiendo a cuando me dices guardarlo en un Object Storage y después que es lo quieres mostrar, porque al utilizar FileInputStream  es porque estas trabajando con un archivo físico no con un archivo en memoria.

Comment: Justamente Roberto es que necesito que guardarlo como zip en el Object Sorage y luego poder descargarlo , y que me muestre el json en el archivo , hoy eso no lo estoy logrando porque cuando lo descargo y quiero abrirlo me dice que el formato es inconpatible.

Comment: el contenido del file lo esta guardando en bytes , ese es el problema necesito convertirlo para que la descarga sea compatible.

Comment: Creo que tu error esta más relacionado a la forma en que estas programando la descarga, podrías poner un ejemplo de código de como la estas realizando para ver un flujo completo y el error al descargar.

Comment: Esta arriba el ejemplo de mi código, lo que hace después es pasarle ese metodo al put del Object Storage de esta manera : storageClient.put(resource, zipFiles(resource, sb.toString().getBytes())); eso solo

Comment: descarga pero cuando quiero abrir el archivo me dice que es un formato incompatible .